# Variable (matrix) changing its value - Java

Tags: java, matrix, multidimensional-array

I'm having a problem in my code. I have an object that contains a matrix of integers, and I'm using this matrix as the original "model" to create other matrices. But at the end, my original matrix has a different value, but I'm not changing in any way.

```
public Matrix generateAdjacencyMatrix(Matrix m)
{
  int storedValue;
  int fitness;
  int[][] auxiliar_matrix = mc.matrixStructure.matrix;
  int[] original_ordering = mc.matrixStructure.matrixOrder;
  for(int i=0;i<mc.matrixStructure.getMatrixSize();i++)
  {
      if(m.matrixOrder[i] != original_ordering[i]) //Only changes if the columns have changed
      {
          for(int j=0;j<mc.matrixStructure.getMatrixSize();j++)
          {
              storedValue = auxiliar_matrix[j][m.matrixOrder[i]];
              auxiliar_matrix[j][m.matrixOrder[i]] = auxiliar_matrix[j][original_ordering[i]];
              auxiliar_matrix[j][original_ordering[i]] = storedValue;
          }
          for(int j=0;j<mc.matrixStructure.getMatrixSize();j++)
          {
              storedValue = auxiliar_matrix[m.matrixOrder[i]][j];
              auxiliar_matrix[m.matrixOrder[i]][j] = auxiliar_matrix[original_ordering[i]][j];
              auxiliar_matrix[original_ordering[i]][j] = storedValue;
          }
      }
  }
  m.matrix = auxiliar_matrix;
  m.setFitness(computeFitness(m.matrix));
  return m;
}
```

This is the method that creates the other matrices. The object "mc" contains my original matrix (mc.matrixStructure.matrix), and exactly after the for loop the value is different.

I am instantiating this object on the constructor method:

```
 public GeneticAlgorithm() throws IOException
{
    this.r = new Random();
    this.matingPool = new ArrayList<>(populationSize);
    this.population = new ArrayList<>(populationSize);
    this.nextGeneration = new ArrayList<>(populationSize);
    this.mc = new MatrixCreator("CS4006_input_file2.txt");
    this.mc.check0or1();
    this.mc.checkDiagonalLine();
    this.mc.checkSymmetry();
    this.auxiliarVector =  mc.matrixStructure.matrixOrder;
    this.auxiliarMatrix = new Matrix(mc.matrixStructure.getMatrixSize());
    this.matrixSize = mc.matrixStructure.getMatrixSize();
}
```

This is it.

Comment: @iccthedral this is Java, not C++.  No object is allocated on the stack, though object *references* may live there.  He does need to do some copying, however, for other reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this ...

```
int[][] auxiliar_matrix = mc.matrixStructure.matrix;
int[] original_ordering = mc.matrixStructure.matrixOrder;
```

... you are making `auxiliar_matrix` and `original_ordering` references to the *same objects* that `mc.matrixStructure.matrix` and `mc.matrixStructure.matrixOrder` refer to.  Modifying those objects via one set of references is equivalent to modifying them through the other, so contrary to your assertion, you absolutely are changing your original matrix.  To avoid this, you need to copy the arrays.

Moreover, you have that problem twofold with `auxiliar_matrix` because Java 2D arrays are arrays of arrays, and arrays are objects, too.  You need to perform a deep copy of that 2D array to avoid modifying the original object.

Something like this should do it:

```
int[] original_ordering = Arrays.copyOf(mc.matrixStructure.matrixOrder);
int[][] auxiliar_matrix = Arrays.copyOf(mc.matrixStructure.matrix);
int i;

for (i = 0; i < auxiliar_matrix.length; i += 1) {
    auxiliar_matrix[i] = Arrays.copyOf(auxiliar_matrix[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm still having some problems with references in Java, I'll definitely do some reading on that...Your answer was perfect! I got know what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign an object to a reference variable, you assign its **reference**. You do not copy it to that reference.

Thus, after an assignment such as

```
int[][] auxiliar_matrix = mc.matrixStructure.matrix;
```

Your `auxiliar_matrix` reference variable now refers to the matrix to which `mc.matrixStructure.matrix` refers.

It's the same matrix, residing on the heap.

Now you are changing data inside the object referred to by `auxiliar_matrix`. For example, here:

```
auxiliar_matrix[j][original_ordering[i]] = storedValue;
```

This means the value will be changed in the matrix both it and `mc.matrixStructure.matrix` are referring to.

If you want to work on a separate copy of your original matrix without affecting it, you have to copy it to a new object first, and then assign this copy to `auxiliar_matrix`. In this case, it's an array of arrays, so you have to create a new array of the same length, and copy over each of the subarrays using `Arrays.copyOf`. Beware of trying to use `Arrays.copyOf` on the array of arrays - the copy is shallow and it will just copy references to the subarrays which would give you the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I would upvote if I had enough reputation...But you helped a lot too!